# Use Xbox One Controller as joystick

Tags: controllers, star-wars-tie-fighter

The 1994 game Star Wars: Tie Fighter Special Edition requires both mouse/keyboard and joystick inputs to play (not at the same time). I have a utility which allows me to use my mouse to emulate a joystick, but this doesn't make for the easiest of controls.

I know that many modern games offer controller support, but since this is such an old game it isn't the case here. The game doesn't let you map the joystick controls to the Xbox One controller, and I haven't been able to find anything in the config files that will help either.

So is there any way to use an Xbox One controller as a joystick?

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to answer, as many of the ways to custom map controls rely on recommendations for software, which are against Arqade rules. The only way to map an xbox one controller to the joystick controls are to use 3rd party software to do so. This can be especially difficult when dealing with xbox contollers.

Instead, I would choose the easier option of re-mapping the joystick controls to keyboard inputs (ie, wasd or ijkl), unfortunately you will still need to use middleware to emulate and map the joystick. Assuming you have familiarity with how to map these controls (as you've said you have done so already to the mouse) I don't think it would be to hard to try a control scheme that relies on buttons instead of mouse inputs (which also suffer from input lag).